# Ruby hash interpolation

Tags: ruby, enumerable

I have a hash of mixed types:

```
stuff = {:pack_one => ["blue_item", "red_item"], :pack_two => [:green_item, :purple_item, :yellow_item]}
```

And I need to convert that into a sentence like:

```
"pack_one contains a blue_item and red_item and pack_two contains a green_item, purple_item and yellow_item"
```

So I assume I need to use Enumerable and iterate over the hash and build the sentence, but I am not sure how?

Comment: How grammatically correct are you aiming for?

Answer (score 6):

My solution. Fit requirements a little bit more strict than @Eureka answer.

```
strings = stuff.map do |key, values|
  "#{key} contains a #{values[0..-2] * ', '} and #{values.last}"
end
puts strings.join ' and '
```

Comment: Clever and short indeed (I did not think of this way to get rid of the ternary operator) :)

Comment: Did not know about this use of Array#*; Array#join is certainly more idiomatic, but I appreciate how terse that is!

Comment: join doesn't seem to be defined for hash.

Answer (score 3):

***If*** you can use [ActiveSupport](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Array.html#method-i-to_sentence), here's a cheat:

```
require 'active_support/core_ext/array/conversions'
stuff.map{|k,v| "#{k} contains a #{v.to_sentence}"}.join(" and ")
```

Result:

```
1.9.3p125 > require 'active_support/core_ext/array/conversions'
 => true 
1.9.3p125 > stuff.map{|k,v| "#{k} contains a #{v.to_sentence}"}.join(" and ")
 => "pack_one contains a blue_item and red_item and pack_two contains a green_item, purple_item, and yellow_item"
```

**EDIT**: To get rid of the Oxford comma, explicitly supply the `last_word_connector` option:

```
1.9.3p125 > stuff.map{|k,v| "#{k} contains a #{v.to_sentence(last_word_connector: " and ")}"}.join(" and ")
 => "pack_one contains a blue_item and red_item and pack_two contains a green_item, purple_item and yellow_item"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution, using `Enumerable#map` and `Array#join`:

```
stuff.map do |k, v|
  "#{k} contains a #{v.size > 2 ? v[0..-2].join(", ") + " and " + v[-1].to_s : v.join(' and ')}"
end.join(" and ")
=> "pack_one contains a blue_item and red_item and pack_two contains green_item and purple_item and yellow_item"
```

Edit: Now fits your requirements perfectly.